# Visual Studio - On publish error: "the url http://0 is invalid"

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, publish

One of our developers is unable to publish a web application via the File System on his machine.  The error is

> "the url http://0 is invalid"

I don't see anything obvious in the project properties in visual studio.  Any ideas what would cause this?

I am able to publish to the same location.  We both have administrative rights to the machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same exact issue. The problem was the leading white space in the Target Path value of Publish Web dialog